# Why does my slider thumb not appear correctly in Chrome or Safari but is fine in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to override the default circular thumb slider and making a more boxy rectangular one. I got the code from here: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

However the code I implement does not work properly on safari or chrome. The circular thumb is still there but I can see the shadow of the box around it sort of. Could someone explain how I can fix this?

Here is the css code:

```
/* CSS declarations go here */
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
  background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
  background: transparent; 
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -14px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; /* Add cool effects to your sliders! */
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    transform: rotate(90deg);

  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    transform: rotate(90deg);

  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range][orient=vertical]
{
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
    width: 8px;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.slider-box {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.slider-box.first {

  margin-right: 25px;
}

.result-box {
  float: left;
}
```

Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/8w0wzxyj/ showing my error

Comment: I have no idea why, but it seems that the `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;` is taking priority over the `-webkit-appearance: none;` which makes absolutely no sense to me, as according to the google chrome inspector, the `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;` has index 32 whereas the `-webkit-appearance: none;` has index 41

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that the selector `input[type=range][orient=vertical]` is more specific than `input[type=range]`. This in turn means that this appearance setting (rest of the CSS omitted):

```css
input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}
```

takes precedence over this one:

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

and hence the default styling is used.

If you ensure appearance is set to `none`, you get full control over how you style the slider, however you'll have to ensure it's vertical yourself.